# Doing multiples of a number in java issues with implementation

Tags: java

Im not sure how to go about making this code.. well at least the total part of this. this is my code right now, I understand the math behind it. I'm just not sure how to implement it. Would I use a loop? here is my code as of right now. I know its not correct but its the start of it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("what number would you like me to multiply: ");
    int number = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("how many multiples of "+number+" would you like to see: ");
    int multiple = in.nextInt();
    int total = 
    System.out.println("total :"+total);
  }
```

here is the output that I would like to get:

```
 What number would you like me to multiply? 4
 How many multiples of 4 would you like to see? 7
 The first 7 multiples of 4 are: 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28
```

Comment: How does `total` play into the desired output? Do you want the total of the multiples shown as well?

Comment: You need to use a for-loop.

Comment: oh no I don't need the total of the multiples shown, i just need it to output the multiples. i was just gonna call that total. @CalvinP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("what number would you like me to multiply: ");
    int number = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("how many multiples of "+number+" would you like to see: ");
    int multiple = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("The first " + multiple + " multiples of " + number + " are: ");
    for(int i=1; i<=multiple; i++){
        if(i>1){
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
        System.out.print(number*i);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks calvin, I think I was making it harder than it needed to be haha. :P @Calvin P

Comment: No problemo :) overcomplicating a problem is very easy to do

Answer (score 0):

Not for this site but:

```
String output = "The first " + multiples + " multiples of " + number + " are: " 
for(int x = 1; x <= multiples; x++){
   output = output + Integer.toString(x*number) + ","; 
}
```

This can be improved using String.format but ill leave that to you. 
Your code could also be improved by doing error checking because right now you could say 'a' for an input and it would crash.

You should look up the basics of programming and also just try stuff you'd be surprised by what you learn just doing random things. There is https://projecteuler.net/ if you need ideas about what to try.